# (Elementary) Trigonometric inequality

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

Any idea for proving the following inequality: $5+8\cos x+4 \cos 2x+ \cos3x\geq 0$ for all real x? I've tried trigonometric identities to make squares appear, and other tricks; but nothing has worked well.

Comment: Have you drawn the graph for $0 \leq x \leq 2 \pi ?$

Comment: Yes, i used wolfram and it seems to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\cos 2x = 2\cos^2 x - 1$ and $\cos 3x = 4\cos^3 x - 3\cos x$.

So, we want to prove that $1+5\cos x + 8\cos^2x + 4\cos^3 x \ge 0$.

The left side is a polynomial in $\cos x$ which can be factored as $(1+\cos x)(1+2\cos x)^2$.

Can you take it from here?